# JQM changepage on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I tried JQM function changepage method after AJAX call success but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

Below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Users/delete_favourites/' + $(this).attr('id'),
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log(msg.FavouriteSuburb);
        alert(msg.FavouriteSuburb.name + " has been successfully deleted from your list of favourites.");
        $.mobile.changePage('/Users/my_favourite_suburbs/', {
            reloadPage: true
        }, {
            allowSamePageTranstion: true
        }, {
            transition: 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a reason why?

Comment: Any errors ? anything happen ?

Comment: No errors it's been success and everything under that was working except changePage function

Comment: It's working now! It seems though async: false was the issue. Thanks!